# WS 2008 R2 giving "Internal Server Error"

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

I have had this problem for a while now and can't find the problem at all. When i open a page it will sometimes give a 500 Internal Server Error message.

This hapens on a website that works perfectly but when i try to upload anything it will give this message(all php settings have been set to either 1gb or 3000 seconds as well as the iis headers).

Also when i open a simple page which does nothing more than include another php page and include a couple of classes the error will occur.

I have no idea what causes this error and would love to hear from any of you on what this could be. I checked the server logs and for the upload issue i found this error:

```
The description for Event ID 1 from source named cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

managed-keys-zone ./IN: loading from master file managed-keys.bind failed: file not found

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

Regards, Dragon

Comment: I doubt your error has anything to do with your 500 error. managed-keys.bind is a file normally associated with BIND, a DNS server. If I were you, I'd collect the PHP log data (set it up if it isn't already) and see what errors you're getting in there. You're most likely to discover the source of your problem there.

Comment: There is nothing logged in php for this error. Nothing whatsoever. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Without a little more info, none I'm afraid. In Internet Explorer, try turning off Show friendly HTTP errors on the Advanced tab and browse to the site again. If PHP is configured as Fast-CGI, its default response is to generate a 500 error and if IE is showing its friendly errors and the actual error isn't very big, IE gets in the way and just shows a 500 and its "helpful" error.

Comment: I still get the EXACT same error as i get in FF and Chrome. any ideas on why this error occurs? At the moment it only occurs when uploading something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your first step is to enable remote errors in IIS.  IIS defaults to "Detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests".  This means that if you were to browse to your error page FROM the server, you'd get the error message, but from a remote pc, you'd get that annoying (but drastically more secure) generic error message:

[image]

To enable errors for remote requests... Open IIS Manager > Navigate to Your Site > Under the IIS Category, open the "Error Pages" section > Open the "Edit Feature Settings" option on the far right navigation bar > Select the "Detailed Errors" option and save:

[image]

That will reveal your error message.  Remember to revert this setting once you are done troubleshooting.